# Is using CNN for feature extraction with a single pooling layer a robust approach?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm investigating the use of CNNs for feature extraction, chaining together with a Gradient Boosting Trees model for classification. The CNN architecture that I have found is most effective is 4 convolution layers with activation after each, before a Max Pooling layer, a flattening step and then 2 fully connected layers.

I'm not particularly experienced with CNNs, but my understanding is that generally the expectation is that you have several sets of convolution layers and max pooling layers (i.e. pool more than once in the architecture) - however I've found that this approach massive reduces the precision and recall of the classification model, although I'm not especially clear why.

I had based my approach on the work done in this article https://towardsdatascience.com/cnn-application-on-structured-data-automated-feature-extraction-8f2cd28d9a7e (apologies if its pay-walled for you).

My model doesn't seem to be overfit, as I have a 40% validation step in the classification model train/test, but I feel sure that I'm missing something as the CNN architecture I've used seems uncommon/not used at all.

For clarity, here is my CNN architecture:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 
=================================================================
conv2d_1_input (InputLayer)     
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)                  
_________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)           
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)              
_________________________________________________________________
activation_2 (Activation)          
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)                
_________________________________________________________________
activation_3 (Activation)           
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)               
_________________________________________________________________
activation_4 (Activation)            
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2          
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)                 
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)               
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (Batch   
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)               
_________________________________________________________________
feature_dense (Dense)         
_________________________________________________________________
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your input and what is their dimension? Also how many number of class?

Comment: Inputs are images which are 250x150x1 (greyscale), theres approx. 1000 of them. Total classes is 50, theres 20 of each class (roughly)

Comment: What type of dataset is this? What are the classes?

Comment: It's a text dataset, and its classifying whether or not the original author wrote a word or not. So one class might be the word 'Apple' written by 'Adam' or not written by Adam if that makes sense?